# Add stars in form for required input fields in virtuemart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, virtuemart

How to add stars(for example red)  in form for required input fields in Virtuemart 1.x?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span>` in your PHP, or add this dynamically using JQuery by using an identifier on required fields (such as `class="required"`) like so:

```
$('<span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span>').insertAfter('input.required');
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont have this class requeired in my code. why? where i can add this?

Comment: I do not have experience of VirtueMart and therefore do not know how it marks up required fields, but you should be able to work this out from looking at the generated source code / library code (and edit if an identifier needs to be added)

Answer (score 0):

@Ing's answer isn't really correct. It should probably be

```
$('<div style="color: #FF0000;">*</div>').insertAfter('[required]');
```

instead.

That's what worked for me at least.